# Re aligning timestamp in an excel data set

Tags: python, arrays, excel

I have to realign an excel data with different parameters in same timestamp. Some row data timestamp were not identical. It is a excel data set. I need to develop a python script to solve it. Thanks.

I need a complete script form importing data file to produce a new data set with re aligned timestamp.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Not sure why you don't just create a pivot table from the base data with the timestamp in the rows and all the data elements in the columns.  Sounds like, literally,  a 30 second task.